# Why the following string- "\ Has been added to my original string?

Tags: c#, string, httpwebrequest

I have this string:

```
requestString="http://staging3.advsnx.net/asa/a.aspx?ZoneID=29447&Task=Get&SiteID=1435&Random=[timestamp]&uuid=qL%2b%2fCPj8PtSrJnnaeOiiztEXTOVaWKcCZkmUBmiN78RTj%2f8t%2byuJsuf8V3dZioD5\tDisplayCamp11\"&VVSID=FhvLbtgO-U2SeK9TnqIFow&debug=true"
```

and i want to perform web request like this :

```
 HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(requestString) as HttpWebRequest;
```

but I'm getting exception beacause my string is now :

```
"\"http://staging3.advsnx.net/asa/a.aspx?ZoneID=29447&Task=Get&SiteID=1435&Random=[timestamp]&uuid=qL%2b%2fCPj8PtSrJnnaeOiiztEXTOVaWKcCZkmUBmiN78RTj%2f8t%2byuJsuf8V3dZioD5\tDisplayCamp11\"&VVSID=FhvLbtgO-U2SeK9TnqIFow&debug=true"
```

I have no Idea what cause this "\ to suddenly appear in the beginning of my original string.

as workaround I've tried to remove this unnecessary string -"\ 
like this:

```
 if (requestString.StartsWith("\""))
                    requestString.Remove(0, 1);
```

but my string is just the same as before.

Comment: No, you're not getting an exception because your string contains a backslash - it doesn't. That's just the debugger displaying the string in C# syntax. Read [ask], show relevant code and show the actual exception. Anyway, `string.Remove()` returns a new string.

Comment: About your workaround, the proper way is: requestString = requestString.Remove(0, 1);